# Is there any explicit theoretical application of Brouwer's Topological Invariance of Dimension theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, topology, spacetime-dimensions

I'm interested in applications of Brouwer's [Topological Invariance of Dimension theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+invariance+of+dimension). I study mathematics but know very little about physics, but I imagined that the Invariance of Dimension theorem would have natural applications in physics just by the statement of the theorem. I was surprised I couldn't find any, so I'm looking for guide on this matter. Is this result simply not interesting in theoretical physics? Or am I misunderstanding something about its applicability or implications in physics?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’d love to be wrong on this, but directly at the physical level (atleast for stuff that’s not aiming at quantum gravity) we assume our manifolds are smooth or atleast a few times differentiable (either for modelling our spacetimes or configuration spaces/ momentum or velocity phase spaces) and there the well-definition of dimension is a trivial application of the inverse function theorem. So one really has to lower the regularity in order for continuous invariance of domain to “kick in”… but at that stage you might wonder whether continuity itself is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Discontinuous functions/curves/tensor fields are of course common place, but having your manifold itself be not smooth seems unlikely. Having said that, one may not want to get distracted by differential structures and rely mainly in topological aspects (see parts of *topological quantum field theory*) so I guess that’s an application?